# Best c# archeticture / pattern for communicating between separate plugins of application

Tags: c#, design-patterns, plugins, architecture

I am currently involved in designing a system from the ground up, and we have come across an architectural design scenario that I'm not sure of the best way to solve - but I'm sure other people have solved and there's probably even a pattern for it.

**The story so far:**

We have a multi-tenent website in which we are implementing various features as Plugins, our clients will choose which plugins they wish to use in their application. And each plugin could have a variety of "widgets" that a user can add to a page. (eg. similar idea to how Android apps often come with widgets that you can add to the main screens).

A plugin can depend upon other plugins to be enabled (eg an eCommerce Plugin would need Payments Plugin). Also plugins can use other plugins to enhance thier functionality (eg Blogs plugin has the option of using the Comments plugin, could also use Comments with eCommerce Products).

As much as possible, we want each plugin to be self contained, with a very skinny plublic interface. We beleive this separation of concerns will give us the best long term flexibility and maintainablility of the overall system.

**The problem:**

When we started to layout all the plugins we currently know about (let alone future requriements), and their depenendencies and possible relationships with other plugins - it started to have a very strong resemlance to a spider web of madness. And we also started to see some Circular References happening.

eg Navigation Plugin needs to know about what Pages are on the site. But you can also add a Navigation widget to a Page.

**The partial/potential solution:**

We were thinking that each plugin should be completely separate from other plugins, but would get info from and communicate with other plugins via Messages. These messages can be broken down into 2 basic types

- request for info from another plugin (Request / Response Messages)
- event notifications (Event Messages)

Both of these message types will be very simple DTO type classes - they shouldn't contain any business logic - just the info required for some other service to process the request, and provide a response.

I have mocked up a very simplified version of a couple of plugins and what we see the solution to their interactions to other plugins would be: http://screencast.com/t/Mdb9wUmMF

In this diagram, the Navigation, Page, Search and Other plugins wouldn't know anything about each other. But they would know about the Messages that are available, and the ProcessMessages interface.

*eg Request / Response Messages*

The Navigation and Other Plugins would know that if it sends a GetPagesRequest to ProcessMessages, it will get back a PagesResponse with all the info they need. (The Nav/Other plugins would need a response to the GetPagesRequest immediately.)

The Navigation and Other Plugins would't know anything about the Page plugin.

*Request / Response Message Requirements*

A plugin that raises a Request Message would always (usually?) expect a Response message immediately.

Only 1 service would know how to process a Request Message, and provide the Response Message that would get passed back to the calling Plugin.

*eg Event Messages*

When a user updates the url of a page in the Page Plugin, the plugin would send a PageUrlUpdated message to ProcessMessages. The Navigation and Other plugin would then consume the PageUrlUpdated message and do whatever it needs to.

*Event Message Requirements*

A plugin that raises an Event would *never* expect a response.
0-Many plugins might consume a given message.

(Tech Note: for Event messages we are going to send them to MassTransit and RabbitMQ - then have 1-n consumers for each message)

**The questions**

1. From a few sketches we've made, the above idea seems to work, and has a lot less inter-dependencies between different elements of the system. But I don't know the name of the design pattern or architectural structure - or if I'm on complete the wrong track. I was hoping that someone could point me to the proper solution - some good documentation and examples would be excellent. (Trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel - and an existing pattern is likely to be more robust and successful)
2. For the Request Messages, we were envisioning some kind of StructureMap-ish mapping from the Request Message to the concrete plugin / service that would process the message. Again - I'm sure that this has been solved before and there's a pattern for it, or we're completely on the wrong track and there's a better solution.

Any help and ideas are greatly appreciated
Saan

PS - I would also have an IWidget in a common project with some basic properties - so the Pages Plugin could just request all classes that implement IWidget to add to a page

Comment: Sounds like MEF is a good place to start - look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Comment: Managed Extensibility Framework is robust enough to handle this architecture. Essentially, plugins alter your default strategy. MEF also provides property and constructor injection so you can instantiate one plugin and inject into another.

Comment: Divide and conquer. Ask smaller more well defined questions about  specific problems like `how can I allow non-related classes consume information frome each others` or `how can a plugin invoke another plugin without create hard coupling between the plugins`.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this question.  I eventually found out that the above question & diagram describes the Mediator pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is subject to a lot of different approaches; but I might suggest Service Oriented Architecture.  Mostly because it can bend to a business in a very quick and agile manner.  This architecture provides many bonuses:

- Lightweight
- Agile
- Code Re-usability

However it does come with an array of hurdles that may need to overcome such as:

- Interoperability
- Security
- Performance
- Persistence

So implementing some of these resolutions may alleviate such an issue.  However, that will require some knowledge of the matter on your part.  As this Architecture is agile, but everything is exposed to a degree.  Additionally what about multiple instances being instantiated?

Those are all potential items you'll have to identify.

What I would personally do, is find the true core of the business- Not the project; but the business.  Then determine what approach would best accomplish that task.  That will be a model that will last as the business core is at it's heart.

Some things I'd highly recommend on this matter are:

- [Patterns Of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008OHVDFM).
- [Implementing Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BCLEBN8).
- [Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity In The Heart Of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00794TAUG).
- [Service Design Patterns: Fundamental Design Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0061LAM5K).

There are a lot of other viable books, but those were some I found very helpful.  As they culminate a vast array of design discussions that involve:

- Lazy Loading
- Unit Of Work
- Repository
- Dependency Injection
- Model Extensibility Framework
- and more...

This will fill in several gaps; but I can't emphasize enough. *No technology is better then one another, they all have pros and cons.  But the technology that captures your business goals the best is the ideal choice*.

And I understand your need for a response to help you, but remember:

> ```
>          Ask not the Elves for counsel, as they both say yes and no.
> ```

Simply because we don't know your project or your business, those goals are going to heavily impact your decision.  Those are things that only you will know.  As I stated things we don't know that you'll want to account for:

- Company Objectives
- Maintainability
- Companies Growth Projections
- Possible Shifts in the Company paradigm.

There are more, but you'll have to account for some of those variables for the applications rate of decay to stay stagnant for awhile.  So the life of the application will endure for quite awhile.

Hopefully that helps, but that is my two cents.

Comment: -1 You list useful ***general*** architecture links, but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @jgauffin Those are all books that are viable for learning several culminations of patterns for several types of systems.  It will give him the tools needed to properly gauge what is required and which architecture may be suit him.  Have you ever read those? I'm sorry you feel that way, but they go into great detail in how to address such questions.

Comment: Thank you. A nice answer on enterprise architecture, and really useful links. +1.